# How to format paragraphs in newfloat

Tags: floats, newfloat

Is there an option in the float package to format the contents of a float type similarly to ordinary text (i.e. indent new paragraphs)?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{Sidebar}{}{}

\title{Newfloat}
\author{Gabriel Christian Alava}
\date{January 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{Sidebar}
    \caption{My first sidebar}

    First paragraph

    Second paragraph. How do I indent this?
\end{Sidebar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not directly, but you can either create a new environment which incorporates the new float type, or redefine the environments created by \newfloat.  But basically all you need is \parindent=\bibindent and possibly \parskip=\baselineskip.

Comment: @Gabriel Christian Alava - did you get this working? I am trying to do something similar and am interested in the answer.  I can set \setlength{\parindent}{12pt} within each note, but something more general?